# re-create a statement using inner join

Tags: sql

I have a statement as the following :

```
select nomF from fournisseur as f, usine as u, puf, produit as p
where f.numF = puf.numF
and u.numU = puf.numU
and p.numP = puf.numP
where u.villeU in ('Paris','Créteil')
```

I want to re-create it using `Inner Join`, but I don't know how, because of the multiple joints in it.

This is what I tried, but I don't know if it's correct:

```
select nomF from fournisseur 
inner join puf on numF
inner join usine on numU
inner join produit on numP
where usine.villeU in ('Paris','Créteil')
```

Could someone please tell me if the statement I wrote using `inner join` will return the same result as the first one.

if not, what's the mistake I've made.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an inner join you still need to specify the columns to join on like you did with your where clause

```
select nomF 
from fournisseur f
inner join puf ON f.numF = puf.numF
inner join usine u ON u.numU = puf.numU
    AND u.villeU in ('Paris','Créteil')
inner join produit p ON p.numP = puf.numP
```

Answer (score 1):

Many databases support the `using` syntax.  This allows you to do what you seem to want to do:

```
select nomF
from fournisseur inner join
     puf
     using (numF) inner join
     usine 
     using (numU) inner join
     produit 
     using (numP)
where usine.villeU in ('Paris','Créteil');
```